# Does HTML meta charset still slow page load?

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, http-headers, meta-tags

According to https://gtmetrix.com/specify-a-character-set-early.html

> It's important to specify a character set in the HTTP response headers of your HTML documents to allow the browser to begin parsing HTML and executing scripts immediately.

> Without specifying a character set the browser is left to figure it out on its own which takes time and therefore negatively impacts your page load times.

Okay, that makes sense.

Specifying character set in the HTTP response header, means it is redundant to also specify it in the HTML `meta` element.

But validator.w3.org feels strongly that it should be specified in the HTML `meta` element. Well, I suppose that's understandable; it is a HTML validator, not an HTTP validator; it doesn't have access to the response headers. Since I want to be able to use the HTML validator to check correctness of HTML output (and not have the validator output cluttered with an error message that I know is unnecessary, but the validator doesn't), I would be inclined to just accept the small redundancy.

However, https://gtmetrix.com/specify-a-character-set-early.html also says

> Setting the character set in the meta http-equiv tag disables the lookahead downloader in Internet Explorer 8. Disabling the lookahead downloader can substantially increase the amount of time it takes to load your page.

Well, that's not good news! It's one thing to incur 22 bytes of redundancy; that's a tiny, tolerable slowdown. It's another thing to push the page load off the fast path, and incur substantial slowdown.

But IE 8 was a while ago. Maybe, hopefully, the above doesn't apply to modern browsers. Maybe they note the character set from the HTTP response header, then quickly skip over the HTML `meta` element, so specifying the character set twice, doesn't significantly deviate from optimal page load speed.

But I don't want to just assume that. Is it actually the case?